# Pupeteer Clicking a button on a modal but only works but only 2 - 3 out of 10 times

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to scrape deck lists from aetherhub for personal use. when you get to the page you have to click to make a modal popup and then no matter what I tried I could not make it copy the text in the body of the modal. Second option is to have it copy to the clipboard and then save that to a variable and then work with the string. Bingo! I made it connect and copy and return the deck list. The problem I am having is that I can not get it to work every time. I have tried putting in waits and delays to try and see that would help but i can not seem to get it to work every time. I mostly get this error "Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement"

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function getcardlist(url) {
    try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    const context = await browser.defaultBrowserContext()
    await context.overridePermissions(url, ['clipboard-read'])
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'}) 
    const exportButton = await page.$('li.nav-item:nth-child(5) > a:nth-child(1)')
    await exportButton.click()
    await page.waitForSelector('a.mtgaExport')
    const mtgaFormatButton = await page.$('a.mtgaExport')
    await mtgaFormatButton.click()
    await page.waitForSelector('#exportSimpleBtn')
    const simplebutton = await page.$('#exportSimpleBtn')
    await simplebutton.click()
    await page.$('.modal.show', { waitUntil: 'load' })
    await page.waitForSelector('.modal-footer > #exportListbtn')
    const toClipBoard = await page.$('.modal-footer > #exportListbtn')
    await toClipBoard.click()
    const copiedText = await page.evaluate(`(async () => await navigator.clipboard.readText())()`)
    await browser.close()
    return copiedText
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    
}
getcardlist('https://aetherhub.com/Deck/rakdos-menacing-menaces')
    .then(returnVal => console.log((returnVal)))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the Error

> "Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement"

It's basically saying that's the requested button/element is not found on the page.
so even if you want or do a `page.waitForSelector` you will get an error (because it does not exist in your DOM). so use headless: false, and inspect element to see if you find your selector

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am aware of the meaning of the error. I have tried in both headless true and false and get the same result.. it works about 20 percent of the time. I need a way to make it work everytime.

Comment: The problem is not headless true or false. is that your element that your waiting for is not in your dom so check it with the chromdevtool

Comment: okay so the problem seems to be that on the first click it changes the card body to give me my second click option. After second click it loads a modal where the final button is contained. How do i make it wait for each to become available? sometimes it hangs after the first click waiting for the body to load. and then sometimes it hangs on the second click cause the modal loads to late.

Comment: I don't have enough information to help sorry.